# FileNotFoundException with JAR in Mac

Tags: macos, file, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to make a java program that accesses a file from within in the jar. I have the code as

```
private static final File LOCK_FILE = new File("src/version2/LOCK");
```

When I run the file alone, it works fine. But when I "Clean and Build" in Netbeans and try to run the jar, I receive a FileNotFoundException. How would I reference this file after it's cleaned and built?
I'm using Mac by the way.

Comment: That's not even remotely how you get to a file inside a jar. A File object can't point to the inside of a JAR. You need to read about getResourceAsStream and whatnot.

Comment: Definitely not. That's why when I was on Windows it worked great. Weirddd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's almost impossible and impractical to write to a file in a JAR. There are times where it is useful, but can be solved by writing the File to a known directory.